# How do I read a multi-line list from a file in Python?

Tags: python, list, file

I have a file which has lists spanned across multiple lines - with the length of the lists as constant. However, in each line the number of elements can varied.
How do I read this file in Python to read each list as a whole?

Edit: Would prefer a non-regex solution.

The file which looks something like this (just for illustration):

```
   [ -6.70031086e-02   5.93684241e-02   1.11689426e-01   1.16174825e-01
      -3.74981388e-02   4.05267589e-02   2.02941950e-02   1.65661901e-01
       9.88883078e-02  -1.86108038e-01  -2.09761858e-01   2.08867267e-02
      -7.34964982e-02  -1.38626635e-01   1.33853648e-02  -1.11527992e-02
       7.19301552e-02   5.71861453e-02  -8.56672525e-02   8.01878721e-02
      -2.27990234e-03   8.93531218e-02  -7.99949542e-02  -3.89122330e-02
       3.07365637e-02  -1.14912149e-02  -1.25382066e-01   1.61550958e-02
      -9.03828740e-02  -8.40659663e-02   2.35458408e-02   6.62269741e-02
      -6.83306251e-03   3.86000201e-02  -2.85124127e-02  -1.22550033e-01
       6.14493713e-02   5.42194061e-02  -9.98141840e-02   3.87526527e-02
      -1.77935660e-02   6.59185136e-03  -7.56490007e-02  -8.04342143e-03
       4.22548652e-02  -4.90937680e-02   7.31833130e-02   4.60098870e-02
      -3.38455513e-02   7.72312284e-02   1.69506043e-01   8.54071528e-02
      -5.15969582e-02  -8.66574422e-02   2.78513003e-02  -8.26551542e-02
       5.72918989e-02  -8.63238499e-02  -1.09750973e-02  -1.04178898e-01
       4.04170994e-03   7.16830865e-02   1.16529778e-01   1.65875465e-01
       1.82720050e-02   1.71985731e-01  -2.09263922e-03  -3.31376195e-02
       1.26107544e-01   1.47209521e-02  -1.41869476e-02   5.07163629e-02
       1.49011686e-01   9.49593708e-02   4.67912182e-02  -8.64533633e-02
       4.12282310e-02   8.19735080e-02   1.49312839e-02   2.14010417e-01
       1.43005610e-01  -6.68876693e-02   1.25497788e-01  -8.12855735e-02
       1.89039335e-02  -7.57512003e-02   4.25233506e-02  -6.90079033e-02
       8.08808357e-02  -3.47024412e-03   2.63141114e-02   1.61882326e-01
       1.25483396e-02   1.45484000e-01   3.12147997e-02   5.61049813e-03
      -1.52215753e-02  -9.00566354e-02   7.78550655e-02   2.32269196e-03
       6.35183901e-02  -1.34039536e-01   1.12368152e-01  -5.65479957e-02
      -1.40751451e-01  -3.24242609e-03  -2.60595884e-02  -3.79961394e-02
       9.53520015e-02   1.18161231e-01  -6.31203428e-02   6.54687434e-02
      -8.70579779e-02   1.64551754e-02  -4.66874018e-02  -2.02252846e-02
       1.81142420e-01  -4.29894254e-02   8.62734243e-02  -1.96067482e-01
      -5.18136062e-02  -1.02697751e-02  -8.20104256e-02  -7.04407394e-02
      -1.37479603e-01   1.51444465e-01   1.46553725e-01   6.87731877e-02]
    [ 0.13552369 -0.05061625  0.13381879 -0.09299553 -0.10647763 -0.02260791
      0.00843107  0.01909993  0.0252617  -0.09204189  0.11444099  0.16380875
     -0.26470438  0.04185624  0.08701419 -0.00960395  0.03196884  0.05695887
      0.03903539  0.0330128   0.0088141   0.03981387 -0.2256397   0.1373885
     -0.00823926 -0.23756374  0.14071368  0.15679301  0.05020505  0.00083234
      0.14197688 -0.17108534 -0.03471961 -0.09328505  0.04228394  0.07565336
     -0.06243521 -0.09347741 -0.00821514 -0.06649745  0.05205032 -0.00554045
     -0.00386953  0.05514322 -0.0234912  -0.11922046  0.14259741 -0.04250529
      0.02933454  0.09837652 -0.04943179 -0.01795183  0.11347186 -0.0262726
      0.14694421  0.00120262  0.02876565  0.06762701 -0.06783341 -0.0130248
      0.0304249   0.04527348  0.15238339  0.01605285  0.02574495  0.03512112
     -0.05733667 -0.09585288  0.05414675  0.14885603 -0.02176115 -0.11798949
      0.10624658  0.04126133  0.0355645  -0.0176413   0.01316    -0.0731855
      0.06095812 -0.03693416  0.05717857 -0.06640249  0.02760602 -0.11397229
     -0.08891453 -0.05422837 -0.00309273 -0.08528782  0.04416328  0.10460843
      0.08477673 -0.03460682  0.26425052  0.027636   -0.01395808 -0.04762371
     -0.11365297 -0.09291256  0.02920797  0.1462263  -0.1354932  -0.00904074
      0.16209167 -0.0351855   0.0287815   0.082674    0.03369482 -0.04522609
      0.01189264 -0.03094579 -0.1829372  -0.0331573   0.03074961 -0.01479802
     -0.06882931 -0.02879945  0.04064524  0.1048708   0.11631119 -0.13730904
     -0.01107442  0.07329052  0.013919    0.02282012  0.14160685 -0.08278389
      0.04416744  0.17811519  0.06306098 -0.15048456 -0.08337893  0.06718753
      0.02712255  0.0626005   0.05940831  0.08399926  0.22958109 -0.06148282
     -0.05348093 -0.05489948  0.18494032 -0.01777483  0.03008986  0.03045709
     -0.09592026  0.17701676 -0.21119906 -0.01997624  0.15930974 -0.03315869 ]
```

Comment: Are you writing numpy arrays to a file?

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

p=re.compile(r'\[.*\]', re.S)
num=re.compile(r'\S+')    
f=open("lst", "r")    
s=f.read()
f.close()    
l=p.findall(s)    
lst=[]    
for i in l:
    tmp=[]
    num_list=num.findall(i)
    del num_list[0]
    for n in num_list:
        if n!=']':
            tmp.append(n)
    lst.append(tmp)

print lst
```

`lst` is a `list` of `lists` read from your file.

Comment: Would prefer a non-regex solution as these could be very slow. --- Updated the question as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
f=open('sample.txt','r')
y=[]
for a in f:
    b=a.split()
    for c in b:
            if c[0]=='[':
                    d=c[1:]
            elif c[-1]==']':
                    d=c[:-1]
            else:
                    d=c
            y.append(d)
f.close()
print y
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regex, just strip and split, mapping to float if you want floats:

```
def sections():
    with open("in.txt") as f:
        tmp  = []
        for line in f:
            data = list(map(float, line.strip(" []\n").split()))
            if line.rstrip().endswith("]"):
                yield tmp
                tmp = []
            tmp.append(data)

from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(list(sections()))
```

Output:

```
[[[-0.0670031086, 0.0593684241, 0.111689426, 0.116174825],
  [-0.0374981388, 0.0405267589, 0.020294195, 0.165661901],
  [0.0988883078, -0.186108038, -0.209761858, 0.0208867267],
  [-0.0734964982, -0.138626635, 0.0133853648, -0.0111527992],
  [0.0719301552, 0.0571861453, -0.0856672525, 0.0801878721],
  [-0.00227990234, 0.0893531218, -0.0799949542, -0.038912233],
  [0.0307365637, -0.0114912149, -0.125382066, 0.0161550958],
  [-0.090382874, -0.0840659663, 0.0235458408, 0.0662269741],
  [-0.00683306251, 0.0386000201, -0.0285124127, -0.122550033],
  [0.0614493713, 0.0542194061, -0.099814184, 0.0387526527],
  [-0.017793566, 0.00659185136, -0.0756490007, -0.00804342143],
  [0.0422548652, -0.049093768, 0.073183313, 0.046009887],
  [-0.0338455513, 0.0772312284, 0.169506043, 0.0854071528],
  [-0.0515969582, -0.0866574422, 0.0278513003, -0.0826551542],
  [0.0572918989, -0.0863238499, -0.0109750973, -0.104178898],
  [0.00404170994, 0.0716830865, 0.116529778, 0.165875465],
  [0.018272005, 0.171985731, -0.00209263922, -0.0331376195],
  [0.126107544, 0.0147209521, -0.0141869476, 0.0507163629],
  [0.149011686, 0.0949593708, 0.0467912182, -0.0864533633],
  [0.041228231, 0.081973508, 0.0149312839, 0.214010417],
  [0.14300561, -0.0668876693, 0.125497788, -0.0812855735],
  [0.0189039335, -0.0757512003, 0.0425233506, -0.0690079033],
  [0.0808808357, -0.00347024412, 0.0263141114, 0.161882326],
  [0.0125483396, 0.145484, 0.0312147997, 0.00561049813],
  [-0.0152215753, -0.0900566354, 0.0778550655, 0.00232269196],
  [0.0635183901, -0.134039536, 0.112368152, -0.0565479957],
  [-0.140751451, -0.00324242609, -0.0260595884, -0.0379961394],
  [0.0953520015, 0.118161231, -0.0631203428, 0.0654687434],
  [-0.0870579779, 0.0164551754, -0.0466874018, -0.0202252846],
  [0.18114242, -0.0429894254, 0.0862734243, -0.196067482],
  [-0.0518136062, -0.0102697751, -0.0820104256, -0.0704407394]],
 [[-0.137479603, 0.151444465, 0.146553725, 0.0687731877],
  [0.13552369,
   -0.05061625,
   0.13381879,
   -0.09299553,
   -0.10647763,
   -0.02260791],
  [0.00843107, 0.01909993, 0.0252617, -0.09204189, 0.11444099, 0.16380875],
  [-0.26470438, 0.04185624, 0.08701419, -0.00960395, 0.03196884, 0.05695887],
  [0.03903539, 0.0330128, 0.0088141, 0.03981387, -0.2256397, 0.1373885],
  [-0.00823926, -0.23756374, 0.14071368, 0.15679301, 0.05020505, 0.00083234],
  [0.14197688, -0.17108534, -0.03471961, -0.09328505, 0.04228394, 0.07565336],
  [-0.06243521,
   -0.09347741,
   -0.00821514,
   -0.06649745,
   0.05205032,
   -0.00554045],
  [-0.00386953, 0.05514322, -0.0234912, -0.11922046, 0.14259741, -0.04250529],
  [0.02933454, 0.09837652, -0.04943179, -0.01795183, 0.11347186, -0.0262726],
  [0.14694421, 0.00120262, 0.02876565, 0.06762701, -0.06783341, -0.0130248],
  [0.0304249, 0.04527348, 0.15238339, 0.01605285, 0.02574495, 0.03512112],
  [-0.05733667,
   -0.09585288,
   0.05414675,
   0.14885603,
   -0.02176115,
   -0.11798949],
  [0.10624658, 0.04126133, 0.0355645, -0.0176413, 0.01316, -0.0731855],
  [0.06095812, -0.03693416, 0.05717857, -0.06640249, 0.02760602, -0.11397229],
  [-0.08891453,
   -0.05422837,
   -0.00309273,
   -0.08528782,
   0.04416328,
   0.10460843],
  [0.08477673, -0.03460682, 0.26425052, 0.027636, -0.01395808, -0.04762371],
  [-0.11365297, -0.09291256, 0.02920797, 0.1462263, -0.1354932, -0.00904074],
  [0.16209167, -0.0351855, 0.0287815, 0.082674, 0.03369482, -0.04522609],
  [0.01189264, -0.03094579, -0.1829372, -0.0331573, 0.03074961, -0.01479802],
  [-0.06882931, -0.02879945, 0.04064524, 0.1048708, 0.11631119, -0.13730904],
  [-0.01107442, 0.07329052, 0.013919, 0.02282012, 0.14160685, -0.08278389],
  [0.04416744, 0.17811519, 0.06306098, -0.15048456, -0.08337893, 0.06718753],
  [0.02712255, 0.0626005, 0.05940831, 0.08399926, 0.22958109, -0.06148282],
  [-0.05348093, -0.05489948, 0.18494032, -0.01777483, 0.03008986, 0.03045709]]]
```

If you are storing the arrays, you might consider using *numpy.save* or *pickle* etc.. Storing in the current format is probably not the best idea.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a another solution:

```
    file = open('database.txt', 'r')
    text = file.read()
    file.close()

    ##  long version
    lists = text.split(']')
    lists = lists[:-1]                      # remove last element which is empty (because of split)
    lists = [i.strip() for i in lists]      # remove possible spaces and tabs
    lists = [i.strip('[') for i in lists]   # remove '[' that is left on beginning of every element
    lists = [i.split() for i in lists]      # split every element to get list
    lists = [[float(j) for j in i] for i in lists]  # convert lists of strings to lists of numbers
    print(lists)                            # result is list of lists

    ## short version
    lists = [[float(j) for j in i.strip().strip('[').split()] for i in text.split(']')[:-1]]
    print(lists)
```

Comment: That's a pretty good solution but i can evaluate that because i know python rather well.  If you add and explanation to you answer about *why* it works the way it works it will make for a better answer.